Make URL of a post pretty using JetEngine
I am currently using JetEngine and I have created a Custom Post Type named Creator. I also created a Taxonomy named Creator Categories. I have a Creator post named Beyond the Wall which I assigned a taxonomy called Arts. When I go to this post, what I want to be in the url is mysite.com/creator/arts/beyond-the-wall. Currently, I did not touch any setup in the permalinks settings, and when I visit this post it only shows mysite.com/arts/beyond-the-wall, how do I achieve the goal above? I am stuck and frustrated as this really seem simple. Any links and references will be so much appreciated.

It seems like this question cannot be answered without a knowledge of the JetEngine extension, which would make it off-topic for our site. You should ask in that extension's support channels, or associated/more general communities.
